# How to clear screen after leaving? Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Title might be misleading, but I am creating a login system with kivy, and I was wondering how to clear what is typed in the TextInput boxes once the user leaves the screen. I found one way, with the built in on_pre_enter function with kivy, but noticed even though it's empty, when the user returns and clicks the box everything comes back up. A way to fix this?

```
<LoginScreen>:
    name: 'login'
    on_pre_enter:
        userid.canvas.clear()
        userpw.canvas.clear()
```

Comment: Could you just set the `text` property of the `TextInput` to ""?. If `userid` is your `TextInput`, just do `userid.text = ""`.

Comment: Didn't think of that, lol. Thanks